# Prevent Airflow from back filling jobs

Tags: airflow

We use the most recent Airflow v1.10.7 and have set catchup_by_default=False in the airflow.cfg and set catchup=False in each one of our dags and set catchup=False in the default args.

But still the airflow backfills and runs the jobs. We really want to use Airflow but this is a show stopper. Also why does the dag run automatically when it's first created even though catchup = False?

Thanks for your help.

**Sample dag:**

```py
from airflow import DAG
from utils.general import Schedule, default_args, AbcComputeOperator
from airflow.operators.http_operator import SimpleHttpOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'abc',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    'email': ['abc@abc.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0
}
```

**DAG_py:**

```py
with DAG(
    'abc_dag,
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=Schedule.daily_0800.value) as dag:

    t = SimpleHttpOperator(
            http_conn_id = 'core',
            task_id='send_abc_alerts',
            dag=dag,
            method='GET',
            data={'Url': 'abc'},
            endpoint='abc/callapi',
            log_response=True,
            response_check=lambda r: True
            )
```

**Docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=abc
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.7
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
            - AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE=America/New_York
            - AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__CATCHUP_BY_DEFAULT=False
            - AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL=http://1.1.1.1:8080
            - AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_STARTTLS=False
            - AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT=587
            - AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - /home/ec2-user/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
              # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "587:587"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

Comment: Can you show your DAG definition and the relevant part of your configuration file? Bit hard to figure out what is going wrong without these.

Comment: included docker compose and dag.py code

Comment: How are you testing this? are you clearing the previous DAGs and checking to see if they run or are you creating a new DAG and waiting for a few minutes to see what happens? 

I'm not 100% sure but I think if Airflow has already created task instances in the database for previous runs it will run them again if they are cleared. 

Try creating a new DAG with a start date 1 hour in the past that runs every 5 minutes. When you activate the DAG it should not create 12 runs, instead it should create 1 run in 5 minutes time.